# Permissions problem with OG group pages

Tags: 7, users, organic-groups

I can't see why it's the case, but one of my site editors cannot edit the content on OG group pages.

Our groups are private, but that users is a member of all the groups in the site and the "site editor" role should allow him to edit any content anywhere on the site.

There are two kinds of groups, which each have their own content type (because they are subtly different), but the role's permissions settings are identical and the "site editor" role has all boxes ticked in the role based access control settings for both the content types. For both the content types, the "site editor" role also has the create, edit (own/any) and delete (own/any) permissions.

The main problem seems to be that the edit menu isn't appearing for that user.

[image: Edit menu screenshot]

I'm evidently overlooking something somewhere, but I can't just see where. Surely the role doesn't also need "administer Organic groups permissions" granted.

Is anyone able to point me to the obvious mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Configuration -> Organic Groups Global Permissions (drupal/admin/config/group/permissions). There you will find really fine grained controls over who can view and edit nodes and fields on your group pages.

Comment: Ah, that's really useful, Daniel, thank you. That suggests to me that the problem is that the Site Editor rôle members are being set up as Group Members, but not as Group _Administrative_ Members. D'you know how I would correct that, please? If it helps, there are specific site rôles who I would like automatically to be Administrative Members of any Group of which they are a member.

Comment: I don't think you can automatically assign og roles at this time. There is an issue called "add rules action for adding og roles for a user per group" (http://drupal.org/node/1327326) that is being worked on; it sounds like what you want. You can, of course, manually assign individual Site Editors as Group Administrative Members. You do that by going to your group page, clicking Group -> People and adding role to selected user.

Comment: Eurgh. That's pretty unhelpful in our context — we have *hundreds* of Groups and we need to create Group Leaders for each one, plus allowing a few Site Editors to be Administrative Members of *every* group. That would be _a lot_ of manual work. I assume I could write something to lock into the user creation hook; is there any chance you could give me a pointer to where I might find some information on how to do that, please?

Comment: Sorry, that's over my head. I'd recommend you look at what Amitaibu has done on the issue I mentioned above. Getting involved in the work that's been done on the rules solution is probably your best bet. - Good luck!